# Outlook won't update first thing in the morning

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011

When I come nt to work and want to check my email, the Outlook client will never update/sync right away.  The last sync time was sometime last night and it says `Not connected to "<Server>"`.

Is there a reason why it does this?  Is there a better way to "wake it up" than to wait 15 minutes?

Comment: Are you logging your account out of your computer at night before leaving?

Comment: No, I'm letting it go to sleep

Comment: Well there ya go then. :)  It's doing its regular 15 minute interval, you sleep the computer, so that interval time stops until the next time the computer wakes, at which point it continues on from where it left off.  Is hitting the Send/Receive button not enough to get the sync up-to-date?

Comment: It is not.  I even try closing the application and re-opening but it doesn't help.

Comment: Next time, log off at night and shut the system _off_ (not sleep). In the morning turn it on and log back in.  Does it work as expected, or is the delay still there?